# Powershell: how to convert system.object values to Array values

Tags: powershell

```
$t3 = Get-Nabc | % { $_.name }
Write-Host $t3.name
Write-Host $t3.gettype()
```

The output is

```
A B C D E F G H I J 
System.Object[]
```

Question:-  I would like to get the output to array and compare with a string

```
$t3 = Get-Nabc | % { $_.name }
$a1 = $t3

for ($i=0; $i -le $t3.length; $i++) {
    if('A' -in $a1[0]) {
        Write-Host 'Match'
    }
    else {
        Write-Host 'Not Match'
    }
}
```

But the code is not working. how to convert/copy the values from system.object to array?

Comment: `System.Object[]` **IS** an array. Question here is what the objects in the array are. You are assuming it must be strings, but are they?  Check with something like `$t3[0].GetType().FullName`

Comment: There are several issues with your code, 1st whatever Get-Nabc returns the first script would only return something if there is a nested property `.Name.Name` 2nd the comparison operator is `-in` not just `in` See  `Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators` or view [online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Can you share the script inside `Get-Nabc`? That would help us to understand what should be compared.

Comment: thank you for reply. The  $t3[0].GetType().FullName gives "System.String"

Comment: $x = @($t3)
Write-Host $x[0]...I used like this, It displayed the first value of array as 'A'. I am not sure am i did correctly are not. But the result is matched to my expectation.